# Drag-and-drop not working in install4j exe - but works great in .jar and develop environment

Tags: install4j

I have a major Java applikation which is now being distributed with the install4j installer on Windows 32 and 64 bit.

This works just fine except for drag'n'drop which breaks when the application is run from the .exe file. If I run the application from the .jar file (or from my development environment) everything (including drag'n'drop) works fine.

When trying to do drag'n'drop running from .exe does not generate an exception in the log file - and the cursor remains with a not-allowed icon.

Is this a bug in install4j or do I need to change some settings in install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have started the application from your installer with elevated privileges. In that case drag & drop with unelevated applications does not work.

Use an "Execute launcher" action to start with original privileges. If you use a "Run executable" action for some reason, set its "Execution account" property to "Run as original user".

Comment: That - together with not setting the execute level to "Require administrator" - did the trick.